# Set active object in Outliner

Tags: interface, selection-tools

In 3D view, click one of the selected objects while holding shift would set it as the active object. My question is how to do this in Outliners instead of 3D View? Because sometimes the object I want to set as active is very small or obstructed by other objects and it's hard to select in 3D View.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hold <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> then click the object name in the ouliner.

Comment: With Blender 2.90 outliner select the object with normal click and Ctrl + Left Mouse Button can be used to toggle selected items without affecting other selections (that is, it adds/removes the clicked object to/from the selection). Unfortunately, the logic seems to be different from Viewport where you have to click with Shift to get the same behavior.